# Excel: Data validations with dynamic range from separate worksheet

Tags: excel

I am trying to create a data validation list whose source comes from a dynamic range on another worksheet. For instance, take the following layout

```
0 | A             B             C
--|-----------------------------------
1 | Category      Item          Price
2 | Dairy         Milk          $ 2.00
3 |               Bread         $ 3.00
4 | Fruit         Apple         $ 0.60
5 |               Bannana       $ 0.75
```

When I select `Fruit` from the first drop down list on another sheet, I would like to be able to select either `Apple` or `Bannana` from the second. Furthermore, if I later add a `Vegetable` category with `Carrot` and `Squash`, as well as another item to `Fruit`, I would like those items to dynamically become part of my data validation selections.

Is this possible without VBA? I would like to keep this "cell formula" based so I don't have to write a `Application.Volatile` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. You have to use a defined name as the source of the validation range, using the [well know](http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/DynamicRanges.htm) OFFSET() trick.

Comment: Saw that exact page earlier... but I didn't read through it the whole way. Didn't think it would work but it did. Thanks for posting it! Made me go back and check twice.