# Excel Data Validation with Tabular Hierarchy with repeated item labels

Tags: excel

I would like to create three validated cells with drop down lists that are dependent on the user's choices in previous drop down lists.

The sourc data, where I get the data from, is the same as you would get from a Pivot, set to "Tabular" format and "Repeat item labels", like this:

[image]

And I would like the user to be able to select first the Level1, ex: Alpha, then I would only show them the option to select either Uno or Due, and then if Uno is selected, item 1 and item 2 like this:

[image]

While there are several sources that address similar issues, none of what I find addresses the issue with this layout. Hope someone can help.

Comment: What happened to stackoverflow? Years ago, whenever I posted a question, I have received five answers within minutes. And now this is my sixth or something question that stays unanswered. Have to look for a different forum

Comment: try the solution at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7678703/excel-data-validations-with-dynamic-range-from-separate-worksheet?rq=1